# Static ArrayList - populate enhanced loop

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I am facing a problem with static arraylists.

I have a player class that takes a string.

```
public Player (String s) {    
    myPlayerName = s;
    myPlayerScore = 0;
}
```

I have a static arraylist of players and a static array of strings.

```
static final ArrayList <Player> MY_PLAYER_LIST = new ArrayList<Player>();
static final String [] TEST_PLAYER_LIST = {"adam", "eve", "john", "mary",};
```

I have a function that populates the arraylist.

```
public void buildPlayerList () {    
    System.out.println("Before - " + MY_PLAYER_LIST.size());
    for (String temp: TEST_PLAYER_LIST) {
        Player tempPlayer = new Player(temp);
        MY_PLAYER_LIST.add(tempPlayer);
        System.out.println("Player: " + tempPlayer.getMyPlayerName());
    }
    System.out.println("After - " + MY_PLAYER_LIST.size());
    for (Player temp: MY_PLAYER_LIST) {    
        System.out.println(temp.getMyPlayerName());    
    }
}
```

However the output I get is;

```
Before - 0
Player: adam
Player: eve
Player: john
Player: mary
After - 4
Player: mary
Player: mary
Player: mary
Player: mary
```

Can anyone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `myPlayerName` in `Player` class is probably static. Remove static keyword.

Comment: please show also the decleration of myPlayerName

Comment: Isn't   `myPlayerName`  static in `Player`?

Comment: static final String [] TEST_PLAYER_LIST = {"adam", "eve", "john", "mary",}; theres an extra comma here

Comment: where do you call this function?? I called it inside main and its working fine

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses
@Eran that was it - thankyou

Comment: @Ricardo -  the extra comma does not effect the array, I just got used to putting it there in case I add more names to the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the Player class looks as follows:

```
public class Player{
    private  String myPlayerName;
    private int myPlayerScore;
    public Player (String s) {    
        myPlayerName = s;
        myPlayerScore = 0;
    }
    public String getMyPlayerName() {
        return myPlayerName;
    }           
}
```

Comment: this will work as it seems that the playerName is static

Comment: Thank you Safwan - yes it was static in the player class that had messed me up

Comment: Good luck Walkerbo